# How to fix: found 15 USB devices not recognized as Android devices?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am getting this message 'No Devices', when I click troubleshoot device connections I'm getting this error:

> found 15 USB devices not recognized as Android devices

When I click next in troubleshooting page I get another error:

> No Android devices detected.

I was able to use my device on my other computer, now using another, so I mean developer mode and other settings on my device are good.

I installed SAMSUNG USB DRIVER FOR MOBILE, and also ADB Driver, but no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Did you enable USB debugging and authorized your computer on your mobile?

Comment: Yes its enabled, and authorised

Comment: And `adb devices` shows nothing?

Comment: Yes nothing is shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have tried:

Updating your platform-tool in your Sdk, either you delete the current and download new and paste in the same root.

The only solution you should be looking at is:
Make sure you have Visual C++ installed. If you do not have this, you get this same error. So I suggest you download it, install, restart your pc, before you launch android studio you should see a popup dialog on your device which needs your to give the computer to have access to your device. Is you see that popup dialog happening it means the problem is solved, so launch Android Studio you should see the problem solved.

Else reinstall your device drivers.

Comment: Visual C++ was not installed, solved, thanks